# ASP.Net Theme not applying to one page

Tags: asp.net, styles

I have an ASP.Net site and one page will not load the ASP.Net themes even though it works for everything else. It's in the same directory as other pages that work. It uses the same master page as working pages. But for some reason it's not emitting the `<link>` element for the style.

Paging is not disabled on the page, and it is enabled across the entire site where it works correctly.

The page isn't incorrect because of a caching issue. I've burned both the site cache and the browser cache and cycled the AppPool involved.

Comment: can you verify that EnableTheming is not set to false in your Page directive

Comment: Is it a new page? Is it getting cached (programmatically) somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, themeing is done in the Page.OnInit(EventArgs) call. I had forgotten the base.OnInit(e); at the end of the call to setup themes on this one page.